# C++ reference to overloaded function is ambiguous

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, overloading

Consider following C++ code:

```cpp
#include <vector>

struct A {
    template<int Count, typename InputIt, typename OutputIt>
    static OutputIt func(InputIt first, OutputIt result) {
        // write some stuff to result...
        return result;
    }
};

template<typename Self>
struct Utils {
    template<int Count, typename InputIt>
    static std::vector<int> func(InputIt first) {
        std::vector<int> vec;
        Self::func<Count>(first, std::back_inserter(vec));
        return vec;
    }
};

struct C : A, Utils<C> {};

auto example(const char* ptr) {
    return C::func<20>(ptr);
}
```

[godbolt.org link](https://godbolt.org/z/9o3Y7x)

`A` implements some functionality `func()` and `Utils` a helper function that simplifies the use of `func()` having the same name but one parameter less(!). `C` just combines those two into one struct.

Now, inside `example()` I would like to call the `func()` defined in `Utils`. However, gcc fails with the error "reference to 'func' is ambiguous" (clang also fails with a similar error message). I expect the compiler to be able to pick the correct `func()` since they differ in their number of parameters. What am I doing wrong here? How can I fix this without having to rename one of the functions?

Thanks!

Comment: I think the actual error is hidden behind the `func` name lookup. If you manually bring all base class `func` names into `C` (i.e.,  `struct C : A, Utils<C> { using A::func; using Utils<C>::func; };`), you will see that you try to resolve `Self::func` while `C` (a.k.a `Self`) is being defined. With `A::func<Count>(...)` it works, but that obviously defeats the idea of the compiler picking the right overload.

Comment: Mmh, if I write `struct C : A, Utils<A> {}` instead (note that Self now is A), the error message is still the same even though A is defined at this point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two issues here. First, you need to explicitly pull in the `func` identifier from both base classes (necessary due to multiple inheritance):

```
struct C : A, Utils<C> {
    using A::func;
    using Utils<C>::func;
};
```

And next, you need a `template` keyword in `Utils::func`;

```
static std::vector<int> func(InputIt first) {
    std::vector<int> vec;
    Self::template func<Count>(first, std::back_inserter(vec));
    //    ^^^^^^^^
    return vec;
}
```

to disambiguate between the desired template instantiaion and another possible but weird expression (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords) for more details).

Comment: Thanks that did the job!